# EDG ,get C++ friend data

Tags: c++, parsing, compilation, edg

I use ***edg*** software (Edison Design Group)to parse C++ code.
I need to get information about all friends classes.

For example for

```
class A;
class B;
class C{
   private:
      int x;
      double y;
   public: 
       friend class A;
       friend class B;
}
```

I need to get that A,B classes are friends for C,when parsing C class.
I tried to look for this info in class_struct_union fields,but unfortunatelly didn`t find anything

For example from the `variant.class_struct_union.field_list` I can get the information for class data members(x and y).I look for the way to get the information about friend classes (A and B)

Can anyone tell me, where can I find the info for freinds classes ?
And may be give some code for example for friends data retreiving?

Comment: Should be `friend class A` (though GCC accepts your code as an extension in some situations, and the EDG documentation seems to accept it too.)

Comment: "Get" how? Be less vague please.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'kal -For example from the variant.class_struct_union.field_list I can get the information for class data members.I need the same source of information for friends classes

Comment: That's just repeating your question. There is no information added by your comment. Let's see some description of how you're "getting" this `class_struct_union`, how you're using the results of the parsing, and so on..

Comment: for (fieldDecl = astType->variant.class_struct_union.field_list, fieldNo = 0;
       fieldDecl != NULL;
       fieldDecl = fieldDecl->next, ++ fieldNo)//a_type_ptr astType

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me, where can I find the info for freinds classes ? And may be give some code for example for friends data retreiving?

Yes, there is someone, who can. As i know, edg is commercial product (closed-source) and if you can use it, you or your company have a commercial support plan. So, you can ask the EDG directly.

And if you have access to EDG code, just try a `grep friend *.h *.hpp */*.h */*.hpp`. Or you can find the definition of `class_struct_union` and check its fields.

AFAIK, there is no access of general public to EDG source so no-one is able to help you when asking this on forums or any open internet site.